# How not to carthage update every time I update my own Carthage framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage

I have an iOS project that uses a Carthage framework which I created for myself.  For convenience let's name them as following.

- MAIN_ PROJECT
- MY_FRAMEWORK

I make changes to MY_FRAMEWORK often that each time I change it I need to run carthage update on MAIN_PROJECT which take quite a time.

I wonder if there is a way to make changes to MY_FRAMEWORK and affect changes to MAIN_PROJECT without calling carthage update but still keeping MY_FRAMEWORK a separated repository framework so I can be used from other projects.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an option to integrate it into your project using Swift Package Manager then Apple has a solution for you:

*Swift packages are a convenient and lightweight solution for creating a modular app architecture and reusing code across your apps or with other developers. Over time, you may want to develop your published Swift package in tandem with your app, or create a sample app to showcase its features. To develop a Swift package in tandem with an app, you can leverage the behavior whereby a local package overrides a package dependency with the same name:*

- *Add the Swift package to your app as a package dependency instead of a local package, as described in Editing a Package Dependency as a Local Package.*
- *Develop your app and your Swift package in tandem, and push changes to their repositories.*
- *If you release a new version of your Swift package or want to stop using the local package, remove it from the project to use the package dependency again.*

Also have a look at [detailled instructions](http://Developing%20a%20Swift%20Package%20in%20Tandem%20with%20an%20App) with links to related topics.